# Php mkdir() is not creating a directory in my web directory

Tags: php

I can't make a new directory in my web server. I think my code is ok to create a directory. Can you tell me what is the error ?

```
$path = "https://wwww.domain.com/astuces/uploads/products/".$id;
if(!is_dir($path)){

    mkdir($path);   

    if(mkdir($path)){
        echo "mkdir is created successfully";   
    }else{
        echo "directory is not created";
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

It's always showing me "directory is not created".

Comment: Why are you running `mkdir` twice ?

Comment: You can't use mkdir with a URL as a parameter. try `mkdir('/path/to/directory/'.$id,0755,true)`

Comment: @AndyGee I'm trying it.

Comment: check permissions on folder

Comment: along with the answers, dont forget to check also the [is_writeable()](http://php.net/is_writable) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just a permission issue, you are doing impossible things.

```
$path = "https://wwww.domain.com/astuces/uploads/products/".$id;
```

**You can never use a url as the path to create a directory in a server.**

The path should be the path in your web server like:

```
$path = "/path/to/your/project/astuces/uploads/products/".$id;
```

And then make sure the apache user has the permission.

If the the parent directory also not exist at first, you have to set the third parameter to `true` of `mkdir`:

```
if(mkdir($path, 0755, true)){
```

Comment: if I use : $path = "../../astuces/uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id; then it's allowable ?

Comment: where DS means a simple forward slash (/)

Comment: @Babu Only if you have the right path and right permission.

Comment: it's now showing me.."mkdir is created successfully". that's mean it's created but I can't see any directory. Now I just set my path look like this : `$path = '../../astuces/uploads/products/'.$id;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

$path = "https://wwww.domain.com/astuces/uploads/products/".$id;
if(!is_dir($path)){

```
$old_umask = umask(0);
mkdir($path, true);  
chmod($path, 0777);
umask($old_umask); 

if(mkdir($path)){
    echo "mkdir is created successfully";   
}else{
    echo "directory is not created";
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

}