# PHP: using full URL in mkdir();?

Tags: php

I need to create a folder using mkdir(); in PHP.

But the issue that I have is that the `$path` is a full URL as opposed to full path on the server.

So i did a search on Google and some say it is possible and some say its not and I found this small code spinets on STO which is here:

[Php mkdir() is not creating a directory in my web directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901350/php-mkdir-is-not-creating-a-directory-in-my-web-directory)

```
$path = "https://wwww.domain.com/astuces/uploads/products/NICE;

if(!is_dir($path)){

    $old_umask = umask(0);
    mkdir($path, true);  
    chmod($path, 0777);
    umask($old_umask); 

    if(mkdir($path)){
        echo "mkdir is created successfully";   
    }else{
        echo "directory is not created";
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    }
```

However, the code above doesn't really do anything.. it doesn't create any folder called `NICE` in the given `$path` string.

My question is, is this even possible USING PHP and if so how.. and what are my other options to achieve this if this is not possible using PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that you need to provide a path as first argument to the `mkdir()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php Passing a URL does not make _any_ sense. How should php map such a URL to a path in the local file system? Should it _guess_ what you mean? Stop assuming that the path component inside a URL is associated with the folder hierarchy in the local file system. That _might_ be the case in a primitive setup, but you cannot simply assume that. Simple counter example: having an `Alias` defined inside the http host configuration.

Comment: @arkascha, ok, thanks. so what are my other options or there is none?

Comment: To build on what @arkascha said, consider: what should happen if you passed a URL to a website you don't own?  What if your site is hosted on a server cluster?

Comment: If you know your website's root directory, i.e. `https://example.com` maps to `/var/www/example.com`, then you can manually substitute that portion and pass it to `mkdir`.

Comment: About other options: this _again_ depends on what folder you actually want to create! Just as I said before. If you simply want to use the path component in the URL and interpret that as a folder hierarchy relative to the document root of the http host, then call `parse_url()` to split the URL and then use the path component you get back for the call to `mkdir()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php